# Cannot add browser platform

Tags: node.js, cordova, browser, npm

I am getting the following when I am trying to add a browser platform to cordova.  It is a newly created application and nothing else (bare bones).

I have tried to remove and re-add and that didn't work.

```
cordova platform add browser
Adding browser project...
Running command: cmd "/s /c
C:\Users\userid\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-browser\4.1.0\package\bin\create.bat c:\devl\cordova\test2\MyApp\platforms\browser io.cordova.hellocordova HelloCordova""
The node identifier for MYCOMPUTER is ABCD123.
Error: The provided path "c:\devl\cordova\test2\MyApp\platforms\browser" is not a valid browser project.
```

Node version: v6.10.2

Cordova version: 6.5.0

Answer (score 1):

Check you have the command window directory here:

If you use this command:

```
cordova platform rm browser
```

Then this command:

```
cordova -d platform add browser
```

With the -d it will enable debugging when adding the platform and you get a better idea of what the issue is.

Comment: As mentioned I did a rm and then a add.  The above was with the debug option.